# Query with incorrect SUM result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables PROGRAMA, TB_ONHAND and TB_BOM in a database in MS Access 2007, the TB_ONHAND stores the physical inventory values, TB_BOM store the materials required to produce a machine, the PROGRAMA table stores the daily production program.

I have a problem when trying to group and SUM a field I called TOTAL.

This is the original query, but I am getting some rows witch x2 values due that TB_ONHAND have the same SUBITEM twice because that material is stored in two different warehouses, I have read that this is fixed with subqueries but I have no idea how, Im trying to understand subqueries with examples, but still no clue how I will add subqueries on my query

```
SELECT 
TB_BOM.SUBITEM, 
TB_BOM.[SUBITEM DESCRIPTION], 
PROGRAMA.FECHA, 
TB_BOM.ITEMTYPE, 
TB_ONHAND.Warehouse, 
Sum(PROGRAMA.CANTIDAD*TB_BOM.[BUILD REQ]) AS TOTAL,  <---This is the value I get incorrect in some cases.
TB_BOM.[PLANNER NAME]

FROM 
(PROGRAMA LEFT JOIN TB_BOM ON PROGRAMA.ITEM = TB_BOM.BOM) 
LEFT JOIN TB_ONHAND ON TB_BOM.SUBITEM = TB_ONHAND.[Item number]

WHERE 
(((PROGRAMA.FECHA)=[Buscar requerimento de material de la fecha: (mm/dd/aaaa)]) AND ((TB_ONHAND.Warehouse)="301"))

GROUP BY 
TB_BOM.SUBITEM, 
TB_BOM.[SUBITEM DESCRIPTION], 
PROGRAMA.FECHA, TB_BOM.ITEMTYPE, 
TB_ONHAND.Warehouse, 
TB_BOM.[PLANNER NAME];
```

This is the query result (note that I deleted some fields like FECHA,ITEMTYPE,WAREHOUSE,PLANNER NAME just to show you the Item numbers and sum values):

```
SUBITEM       Physical inventory    TOTAL   CORTOS
30-5865/01-801      5.00             82  -77
```

But its totally wrong it should Sum a TOTAL of 41, I have noted that this is caused because in the table TB_ONHAND the same SUBITEM has two rows because that material is stored in different warehouses.

Correct result should be:

```
SUBITEM       Physical inventory    TOTAL   CORTOS
30-5865/01-801      5.00             41  -36
```

BTW I get correct Sums almost with every Subitem numbers, because those Subitems appears only once in TB_ONHAND, those material that get wrong Sum values is because they have 2 or more rows in TB_ONHAND.

I would be very grateful for any help, my English is not perfect, so I hope my thread is understandable.

Comment: well, you said it yourself, the wrong result is because the data appears twice in the `TB_ONHAND` table, with different warehouses. Which one should you choose?, do you even *need* the warehouse information?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. As @Lamak stated, you know of the cause - so what kind of help are you seeking at this point?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, a subquery should handle it.  You would try something like this:

```
SELECT SUBITEM, [SUBITEM DESCRIPTION], FECHA, ITEMTYPE, 
   TOTAL, [PLANNER NAME], TB_ONHAND.Warehouse
FROM
   (SELECT 
    TB_BOM.SUBITEM, 
    TB_BOM.[SUBITEM DESCRIPTION], 
    etc...) SUBQUERY1
LEFT JOIN TB_ONHAND ON SUBQUERY1.SUBITEM = TB_ONHAND.[Item number]
WHERE ((TB_ONHAND.Warehouse)="301")
```

Remove the part that calculates TB_ONHAND.Warehouse in the inner query.  This will avoid duplicating calculations on the total column while still giving you full warehouse information in the outer query.

Comment: Where is the total column?

Comment: The total column is in the subquery the same way it was originally:  Sum(PROGRAMA.CANTIDAD*TB_BOM.[BUILD REQ]) AS TOTAL.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a subquery to get only the distinct results from the tb_OnHand table, which should remove duplicates:

```
SELECT 
TB_BOM.SUBITEM, 
TB_BOM.[SUBITEM DESCRIPTION], 
PROGRAMA.FECHA, 
TB_BOM.ITEMTYPE, 
distinct_TB_ONHAND.Warehouse, 
Sum(PROGRAMA.CANTIDAD*TB_BOM.[BUILD REQ]) AS TOTAL,  <---This is the value I get incorrect in some cases.
TB_BOM.[PLANNER NAME]

FROM 
(PROGRAMA LEFT JOIN TB_BOM ON PROGRAMA.ITEM = TB_BOM.BOM) 
LEFT JOIN (select distinct warehouse, [Item number] from TB_ONHAND where ((Warehouse)="301")) as distinct_TB_ONHAND ON TB_BOM.SUBITEM = distinct_TB_ONHAND.[Item number]

WHERE 
((PROGRAMA.FECHA)=[Buscar requerimento de material de la fecha: (mm/dd/aaaa)]))

GROUP BY 
TB_BOM.SUBITEM, 
TB_BOM.[SUBITEM DESCRIPTION], 
PROGRAMA.FECHA, TB_BOM.ITEMTYPE, 
distinct_TB_ONHAND.Warehouse, 
TB_BOM.[PLANNER NAME];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want stuff in warehouse 301 -- get rid of the joins and write what you want then it is clear how to make it work

```
SELECT 
  TB_BOM.SUBITEM, 
  TB_BOM.[SUBITEM DESCRIPTION], 
  PROGRAMA.FECHA, 
  TB_BOM.ITEMTYPE, 
  TB_ONHAND.Warehouse, 
  Sum(PROGRAMA.CANTIDAD*TB_BOM.[BUILD REQ]) AS TOTAL,  
  TB_BOM.[PLANNER NAME]
FROM PROGRAMA
LEFT JOIN TB_BOM ON PROGRAMA.ITEM = TB_BOM.BOM 
WHERE PROGRAMA.FECHA=[Buscar requerimento de material de la fecha: (mm/dd/aaaa)]
  AND TB_BOM.SUBITEM IN (SELECT [Item number] FROM TB_ONHAND WHERE Warehouse="301")
GROUP BY 
  TB_BOM.SUBITEM, 
  TB_BOM.[SUBITEM DESCRIPTION], 
  PROGRAMA.FECHA,
  TB_BOM.ITEMTYPE, 
  TB_BOM.[PLANNER NAME];
```

Writing the code directly to what you want make the intention clear, maintenance easier and (often but not always) the optimizer able to improve performance.